# 18.04.2 slow opening applications

Tags: 18.04, performance

I just clean installed 18.04 (used 16.04 before) and to be honest I could not be more disappointed. The OS looks wonderful, but the performance is dog shit compared to 16.04. Opening new tabs in firefox can take several seconds and starting atom or intellij also can take several seconds or sometimes even freeze.

I have a good laptop - ASUS UX430UQ, intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4, 15,6 Gbit ram and a 512 GBit SSD.

Why is this happening and is there any relative easy way to solve this? I love Ubuntu and will go back to 16.04 if not resolved, but this was a big disappointing and I was expecting more from Canoncial.

Here are some sceen dumps with performance stuff:

[$ top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6nNd.png)

[$ vmstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMR2k.png)

[down, up and response time internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW8lr.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling and the OS crashing a few times I just erased the disk and installed it again. It runs good now.

Additional info for those interested. One of the crashes or automatic log out came when I was trying to open Atom. The core file that was dumped contained this information:

[$ file core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eykx.png)